# Outlined sketch to PDF, Corel draw?

Tags: sketching

How do I transfer a simple outlined sketch 550mm x 290mm to a PDF file or to vector graphics in Corel draw ?

Comment: If the image is a bitmap/raster image, then have you tried Trace Bitmap in Corel Draw? More info [here](http://learn.corel.com/tutorials/convert-images-to-vector-files-quickly-and-easily-with-powertrace/)

Answer (score 1):

Start with Trace Bitmap to get your art into curves, then export to the desired file type!